# Multitouch interaction compiled on Linux system with a on/board pc

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java, touchscreen, embedded

I assume something is wrong in my setup but can't figure out what it is.

I'm on Intel core i7 board with Waveshare touch screen. As Operating system I tried Lubuntu, Ubuntu 18.04, Ubuntu 19.04 and also Debian.
But all cases only return one touch point (that is actually being interpreted as a mouse input rather than touch point). I have tried touchegg, and several other solutions.

The only thing keeps me going is the fact that C++ based apps, like Chromium and the built-in image viewer, actually operate correctly with multitouch gesture. Therefore it IS software solvable!

My end goal is to have multitouch points from the touch screen in order to write a Java app. I am aware that's weird setup, but the client already have most of his code in Java and I can't change that.

I have found a C++ library called "tslib" that looks like the right solution but I cant seem to make it work as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: @zagrimsan thanks for the edits. all are ok, except for the deepin -- Debian. Deepin is an os that based on Linux. Check it out, quite nice. And I also tried Android system. In Android I have multitouch but can't seem to make anything else.

Comment: Ouch, my bad, never heard of Deepin before so I incorrectly assumed it was a typo. I submitted another edit to fix that. (of course you could've edited it back yourself, too, using the "edit" link under the post)